# Classes that are not persisted

Tags: symfony

Just a general question about 'proper' use of symfony. I see a need for classes that are not persisted in my application. They are objects handed between services and sometimes templates that are not saved in the database.

Is this a valid way of handling temporary data in Symfony. Should they be entities? Or should I focus on not using separate objects and just try to keep everything within entities. Where should I save these class files?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to learn more about DDD approach, where you can concentrate on domain level of your application first.
This approach is described http://williamdurand.fr/2013/08/20/ddd-with-symfony2-making-things-clear/ and a good point to clear about folders structure on Symfony2 is this article http://williamdurand.fr/2013/08/07/ddd-with-symfony2-folder-structure-and-code-first/

Comment: Just having a read of those links - very interesting stuff. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You're can save these classes anywhere. Doctrine is only one of many data storages. For example, you can have classes that are persisting in external external webservices and save these in **Model** directory(However, better if you save these in directories by business logic).